# SSOAgentModule throwing an error in related to LDAP

Tags: web8, sso, web8-cu1

I was trying to Implement MFA as a POC for one of our CME with the help of this [Article](https://yatb.mitza.net/search/label/ADFS), post I set user name in request SSO header. Tridion SsoAgentHttpModule throwing me below error

> The object does not exist.
>
> Component: SsoAgentHttpModule
>
> Errorcode: 0 User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE StackTrace Information
>   Details:    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.ConstructResponse(Int32
>   messageId, LdapOperation operation, ResultAll resultType, TimeSpan
>   requestTimeOut, Boolean exceptionOnTimeOut)    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.SendRequest(DirectoryRequest
>   request, TimeSpan requestTimeout)    at
>   Tridion.Security.DirectoryService.GetResponse(LdapConnection
>   connection, SearchRequest request, Int32 referralHops)    at
>   Tridion.Security.DirectoryService.GetUser(String userName)    at
>   Tridion.Security.Web.SsoAgentHttpModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)

I see there is nowhere LdapAuthenticationHttpModul enabled in below

> '%TRIDION_HOME%\web\Web.config' and
>   '%TRIDION_HOME%\webservices\Web.config', in the
>   '/configuration/system.webServer/modules' section

Does anyone face a similar issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSO Agent can be configured to do an LDAP lookup of the user name coming in through an HTTP header (in order to retrieve additional info about the user).

Check your SSO configuration (in the TCM MMC snap-in) whether a Directory Service has been configured (this is optional).